# Horizontal chart change colors

Tags: javascript, charts

I need help using chartsjs. I was able to create a horizontal chart [image]

but I need to make them look like this.

[image]

The horizontal bar should be divided into four sections. I'm not sure if it is even possible. here is my code so far. Please help. I anyone can recommend ideas on how to make it work that way, it would be a great help.

```js
function createCharts(){
  var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("gender_chart"), {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Male", "Female"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Population (millions)",
        backgroundColor: ["#D98880","#F8C471","#D35400","#34495E","#641E16"],
        data: [44,56]
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Gender'
      }
    }
  });

  var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("age_chart"), {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
      labels: ["20-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Population (millions)",
        backgroundColor: ["#D98880","#F8C471","#D35400","#34495E","#641E16"],
        data: [35,25,30,10]
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Age Group'
      }
    }
  });

  var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("tenure_chart"), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ["1 yr and below", "2 years", "3 years +"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Population (millions)",
        backgroundColor: ["#D98880","#F8C471","#D35400","#34495E","#641E16"],
        data: [33,48, 19]
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Agent Tenure'
      }
    }
  });

  var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("ccbg_chart"), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ["With", "Without"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Population (millions)",
        backgroundColor: ["#D98880","#F8C471","#D35400","#34495E","#641E16"],
        data: [72,28]
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Call Center Background'
      }
    }
  });

  var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("educ_chart"), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ["Primary", "Secondary", "Bachelor", "Doctorate"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Population (millions)",
        backgroundColor: ["#D98880","#F8C471","#D35400","#34495E","#641E16"],
        data: [11,36,48,5]
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Educational Background'
      }
    }
  });

  var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("mset_chart"), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ["MSET1", "MSET2", "MSET3", "MSET4", "MSET5" ],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Population (millions)",
        backgroundColor: ["#D98880","#F8C471","#D35400","#34495E","#641E16"],
        data: [20,13,43,10,14]
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'MSET'
      }
    }
  });
}

function updateCharts(){

 var month = document.getElementById('month_select').options[document.getElementById('month_select').selectedIndex].value;
 var month2 = document.getElementById('month_select').options[document.getElementById('month_select').selectedIndex].text;

 var male;
 var female;

 if ((month == 1) | (month == 3) | (month == 5) | (month == 7) | (month == 9) | (month == 11)){
  male=52;
    female=48;

  age1=20;
  age2=30;
  age3=45;
  age4=5;

  tenure1=13;
  tenure2=40;
  tenure3=47;

  with_bg=13;
  without_bg=87;

  educ1=12;
  educ2=25;
  educ3=40;
  educ4=33;

  mset1=10;
  mset2=20;
  mset3=30;
  mset4=30;
  mset5=10;

 } else {
  male=39;
  female=61;

  age1=15;
  age2=35;
  age3=20;
  age4=30;

  tenure1=38;
  tenure2=50;
  tenure3=12;

  with_bg=28;
  without_bg=72;

  educ1=50;
  educ2=3;
  educ3=22;
  educ4=25;

  mset1=3;
  mset2=12;
  mset3=15;
  mset4=50;
  mset5=20;
 }

  var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("gender_chart"), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ["Male", "Female"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Population (millions)",
        backgroundColor: ["#D98880","#F8C471","#D35400","#34495E","#641E16"],
        data: [male,female]
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Gender'
      }
    }
  });

  var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("age_chart"), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ["20-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Population (millions)",
        backgroundColor: ["#D98880","#F8C471","#D35400","#34495E","#641E16"],
        data: [age1,age2,age3,age4]
      }
    ]},
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Age Group'
      }
    }
  });

  var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("tenure_chart"), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ["1 yr and below", "2 years", "3 years +"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Population (millions)",
        backgroundColor: ["#D98880","#F8C471","#D35400","#34495E","#641E16"],
        data: [tenure1,tenure2, tenure3]
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Agent Tenure'
      }
    }
  });

  var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("ccbg_chart"), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ["With", "Without"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Population (millions)",
        backgroundColor: ["#D98880","#F8C471","#D35400","#34495E","#641E16"],
        data: [with_bg,without_bg]
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Call Center Background'
      }
    }
  });

  var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("educ_chart"), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ["Primary", "Secondary", "Bachelor", "Doctorate"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Population (millions)",
        backgroundColor: ["#D98880","#F8C471","#D35400","#34495E","#641E16"],
        data: [educ1,educ2,educ3,educ4]
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Educational Background'
      }
    }
  });

  var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("mset_chart"), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ["MSET1", "MSET2", "MSET3", "MSET4", "MSET5" ],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Population (millions)",
        backgroundColor: ["#D98880","#F8C471","#D35400","#34495E","#641E16"],
        data: [mset1,mset2,mset3,mset4,mset5]
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'MSET'
      }
    }
  });
}

function crtbtnMonth() {
  var month2 = document.getElementById('month_select').options[document.getElementById('month_select').selectedIndex].text;

 var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 var container = document.createElement("div");
 container.className = "btn_container";
  var t = document.createTextNode(month2);
  container.appendChild(t);
  btn.appendChild(container);
  document.getElementById("CreatedBtn").appendChild(btn);
}

function crtbtnModality() {
 var Modality = document.getElementById('modality_select').options[document.getElementById('modality_select').selectedIndex].text;

 var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 var container = document.createElement("div");
 container.className = "btn_container";
  var t = document.createTextNode(Modality);
  container.appendChild(t);
  btn.appendChild(container);
  document.getElementById("CreatedBtn").appendChild(btn);
}

function crtbtnAccount() {
  var Account = document.getElementById('account_select').options[document.getElementById('account_select').selectedIndex].text;

  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var container = document.createElement("div");
  container.className = "btn_container";
  var t = document.createTextNode(Account);
  container.appendChild(t);
  btn.appendChild(container);
  document.getElementById("CreatedBtn").appendChild(btn);
}

function crtbtnLOB() {
  var LOB = document.getElementById('lob_select').options[document.getElementById('lob_select').selectedIndex].text;
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var container = document.createElement("div");
  container.className = "btn_container";
  var t = document.createTextNode(LOB);
  container.appendChild(t);
  btn.appendChild(container);
  document.getElementById("CreatedBtn").appendChild(btn);
}

function crtbtnZone() {
  var Zone = document.getElementById('zone_select').options[document.getElementById('zone_select').selectedIndex].text;

  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var container = document.createElement("div");
  container.className = "btn_container";
  var t = document.createTextNode(Zone);
  container.appendChild(t);
  btn.appendChild(container);
  document.getElementById("CreatedBtn").appendChild(btn);
}
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-family: "verdana";
}

header{
 text-align: left;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: #6495ED;
 font-family: "verdana";
}

header h1{
 color: #ffffff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

li {
 list-style: none;
}

.main_menu {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}

.main_menu li{
 float: left;
 padding: 10px;
}

.body_inner {
 max-width: 1400px;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding: 0px 20px;
}

.drop_selection {
 text-align: left;
}

.chartContainer {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
}

.chartContainer .chart_single{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 32.5%; 
 margin: auto;
 padding: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 
}

.chartContainer .chart_single canvas{
 background-color: #e8e8e8;
 padding: 10px;
}

#CreatedBtn {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 20px 0;

}

#CreatedBtn:first-child {
 margin-left:0px;
}

#CreatedBtn button {
 float: left;
 border: none;
 background-color:transparent;
 margin: 5px;
}

#CreatedBtn button .btn_container{
 padding: 5px 10px;
 background-color: #888888;
}

/* PIP Page */

.charts_header_divs {
 margin-top: -20px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 600;
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: #333333;
 width: 28%;
}

.pip_charts_container {
 width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #333333;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.pip_charts_container .days_column{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 28%;
 float: left;
 background-color: #efefef;
 height: 250px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    padding-left: 0px; 
}

.pip_charts_container .days_column .charts_header_div{
 text-align: center;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background-color: #1995ad;
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.pip_charts_container .days_column_inner{
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 background-color: #bcbabe;
 height: 250px;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-left: 0px; 
}

.pip_charts_container .days_column .days_row{
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 font-size: 14px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.pip_charts_container .days_column .days_row .days_label{
 width: 48%;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 padding-left: 60px;
 
}

.pip_charts_container .days_column .days_row .days_label div{
 text-align: center;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 margin: auto;
 float: left;
}

.pip_charts_container .days_column .days_row .days_label div:first-child{
 text-align: center;
 border: 1px solid #336b87;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 padding-top: 10px;
 margin: auto;
 float: left;
 font-size: 14px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 font-weight: 500;
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: #90afc5; 
}

.pip_charts_container .days_column .days_row .days_counter{
 width: 48%;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
}

.pip_charts_container .days_column .days_row .days_counter div{
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #90afc5;
 margin: auto;
 width: 80px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #80bd9e;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.charts_column .charts_header_div{
 text-align: center;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 
 float: left;
}

.charts_column .charts_header_div div{
 border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 2px; 
 background-color: #1995ad;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: 500;
}

.pip_charts_container .charts_column_inner{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 70%;
 float: left;
 padding: 15px;
 border: 2px solid #888888;
}

.pip_charts_container .charts_column .charts_header{
 float: left;
 height: 20px;
}

.pip_charts_container .charts_column .charts_header div{
 float: left;
}

.pip_charts_container .charts_column .charts_container1 {
 width: 49%;
 float: left;
}

.pip_charts_container .charts_column .charts_container1 .days_chart_single{
 width: 49%;
 float: left;
}

.pip_charts_container .charts_column .charts_container2 .days_chart_single .chart_name{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 14px;
 height: 45px;
}

.pip_charts_container .charts_column .charts_container1 .boxes{
 width: 49%;
 float: left; 
 margin-top: 30px;
}

.pip_charts_container .charts_column .charts_container1 .boxes .box_single{
 float: left;
 width: 49%;
 border: 1px solid #888888;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}

.pip_charts_container .charts_column .charts_container2 {
 width: 49%;
 float: left;
}

.pip_charts_container .charts_column .charts_container2 .days_chart_single{
 width: 49%;
 float: left;
}


.emp_table {
 width: 100%;
}

.emp_table .empheader{
 background-color: #1995ad;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px 2px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.emp_table .empheader:first-child{
 border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.emp_table .empheader:last-child{
 border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}

.emp_row {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 font-size: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.emp_row .empcol1{
 width: 8%;
}

.emp_row .empcol2{
 width: 8%;
}

.emp_row .empcol3{
 width: 8%;
}

.emp_row .empcol4{
 width: 8%;
}

.emp_row .empcol5{
 width: 9%;
}

.emp_row .empcol6{
 width: 8%;
}

.emp_row .empcol7{
 width: 8%;
}

.emp_row .empcol8{
 width: 8%;
}

.emp_row .empcol9{
 width: 8%;
}

.emp_row .empcol10{
 width: 10%;
}

.emp_row .empcol11{
 width: 8%;
}

.emp_row .empcol12{
 width: 8%;
}

.emp_row div{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="functions.js"></script>

<header><h1>Performance Management Tool > P1 </h1></header>
<div class="body_inner">
  <div class="charts_header_div">Pending Enrollment</div>
  <div class="drop_selection">
    <div id="output"></div>
    <form>
      <select id = "month_select" name="month" onchange="updateCharts();crtbtnMonth()">
        <option value="0">All</option>
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
      </select>
      <select id = "Modality_select" name="modality" onchange="updateCharts();crtbtnModality()">
        <option value="0">All</option>
        <option value="1">chat</option>
        <option value="2">email</option>
      </select>

      <select id = "Account_select" name="account_select" onchange="updateCharts();crtbtnAccount()">
        <option value="0">All</option>
        <option value="1">Sony</option>
        <option value="2">Capital One</option>
        <option value="3">Intel</option>
      </select>

      <select id = "LOB_select" name="LOB" onchange="updateCharts();crtbtnLOB()">
        <option value="0">All</option>
        <option value="1">Sound</option>
        <option value="2">Video</option>
      </select>

      <select id = "Zone_select" name="Zone" onchange="updateCharts();crtbtnZone()">
        <option value="0">All</option>
        <option value="1">Blue</option>
        <option value="2">Green</option>
        <option value="3">Red</option>
        <option value="4">White</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id = "CreatedBtn"></div>
  <div class="chartContainer">   
    <div class="chart_single">        
      <canvas id="gender_chart" ></canvas>    
    </div>
    <div class="chart_single">        
      <canvas id="age_chart" ></canvas>    
    </div>
    <div class="chart_single">        
      <canvas id="tenure_chart" ></canvas>    
    </div>
    <div class="chart_single">        
      <canvas id="ccbg_chart" ></canvas>    
    </div>
    <div class="chart_single">        
      <canvas id="educ_chart" ></canvas>    
    </div>
    <div class="chart_single">        
      <canvas id="mset_chart"></canvas>    
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>   
    function addData(whatChart) {
      whatChart.data.datasets[0].data[2] = 8;
      whatChart.data.labels[2] = "Unknown";
      whatChart.update();
    }
    createCharts();
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Your data structure is not suitable for this type of chart.

Comment: yes you  are right, I'm still learning how to do things. I found the what I need. its here https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-types/html5-stacked-bar-chart/